# Why does the entry ".." exists in the root directory?

Tags: linux, operating-system, filesystems

I understand the importance of the "." and ".." entries in general, by having ".." in the root directory seems pretty useless.. Does anyone knows why it is that way?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Also see [Why does the root directory '/' have a reference to its “parent”?](https://superuser.com/q/804162/173513) on Super User.

Answer (score 1):

It makes it so arbitrary path traversal upwards always leads to an absolute path. Root is its own parent directory. For instance /../../../srv is still a usable directory and is equivalent to /srv

See http://teaching.idallen.com/cst8207/12f/notes/160_pathnames.html#dot-and-dot-dot-.-and-.. for a good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It is that way for consistency. If the root has a .. entry, then it can be treated identically with any other directory. Thus, programmers do not have to do a check to see if the directory is the root before including a .. reference.